# Highlighting only the first char of each word

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Jquery Autocomplete - highlighting the first char of each word.

For example :

If I am searching with the word 'a' in the autocomplete, It should filter by words of first letter->

South Asian Cultural Association
Angel House of Georgia

result should be by highlighting the first char of each word and the filter also should be based on the first char..

Excepted Output :

South **A**sian Cultural **A**ssociation
**A**ngel House of Georgia

Can any one help me on this ?

Comment: please show us your code

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works:

```
$( "#project" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: function(request, response) {
        var matcher = new RegExp("(?<!\w)" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) + "\w+", "i");
        response($.grep(tags, function(item) {
            return matcher.test(item);
        }));
    },
  create: function () {
        $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $('<li>')
                .append('<a>' + item.label.replace($("#project").val(), "*"+ $("#project").val() +"*") + '</a>')
                .appendTo(ul);
        };
    }
})
```

});

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the autocomplete should check for each word first char of the sentence and highlight the result based on that.
For Example :

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the autocomplete should check for each word first char of the sentence and highlight the result based on that.
For Example : If I am searching with the word "s", It should filter the below result ---- Pet Rescue Society , South Asian Cultural Association , Sponsors for Educational Opportunity.In this "Pet Rescue Society" Society is the 3 word of the sentence but first char of the word. Can any one help for this.

Comment: I updated the regexp, it should work now as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic proof of concept for what you are trying to do...

```
$("#entered").on("input", function () {
    var content = $('#content').html();
    var pattern = "( " + $("#entered").val() + ")";
    var regex = new RegExp( pattern, "gi");

    var output = content.replace( regex, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');

    $('#output').html( output );
});
```

Here's a fiddle with more code... http://jsfiddle.net/bashe/t7oxzejh/1/